# Unable to Login in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, login-screen

My system got hanged while I was using Nautilus to copy a file to one of the root directories, except I was still able to go to virtual console(ctrl+alt+F1) so I tried reboot as I was in a hurry in doing my task. But later on when I tried to login, a black screen appears and it comes back to the lock screen.

I have checked few related issues posted on forums, which suggested to

- [check](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300682/what-represent-xauthority-file#300737) for .Xauthority file(which I did not find in my system and the
  other systems that are working, I mean are able to login)
- and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949111/debian-login-loop) solution, which I am unsure to proceed or not

I have reinstalled the O.S, but would be happy to know why this has happened and know how to solve such issue.

the [dmesg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B96vRfIapairYjFuTmx3MWdURkE) file and
the [Xorg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B96vRfIapairLXdlWlc3b2N2X2c) file

Comment: Could you post some logs to help with diagnosing the problem? X logs (`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for the latest logs) and potentially dmesg could show errors causing this.

Comment: Sry, for late reply I have udated the question with the files asked for@ethanwu10